# .NET Compact Framework PowerToys

Tags: .net, compact-framework

I'm trying to do some development on our legacy .NET Compact Framework 3.5 application (a warehouse application running on Windows CE/Windows mobile devices).

On opening the project in Visual Studio 2008, I get this error:

> The imported project
> "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\Microsoft.CompactFramework.CSharp.targets"
> was not found.  Confirm that the path in the  declaration is
> correct, and that the file exists on disk.

I think this is caused by the absence of "Power Toys for .NET Compact Framework 3.5", probably removed by a recent upgrade to Windows 2004.

This package used be available at this URL: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13442

However, Microsoft seems to have removed it, and I can't find any mirrors online.

Does anyone have a copy of this package, to be made available for download?

Comment: The CF3.5 PowerToys is a clooection of tools but does not install new CF components. You have another issue: The CF3.5 is not installed or you are using a VS 2008 Express edition without CF compiler. May be related to https://www.toradex.com/community/questions/23932/cant-open-net-projects-in-vs2015-after-windows-10.html. Possibly you better install Windows XP or 7 in a virtual machine and then setup the VS2008 development in this VM. It is unbelievable how Windows Updates break a current install. Search for "Microsoft.CompactFramework.CSharp.targets"

Comment: When you say "Windows 2004" I assume you mean "Windows 10 build 2004"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have upgraded Windows 10 and ran into the same issues, that the Power Toys install was mangled.

I did find the msi using the wayback machine:
https://web.archive.org/web/*/https://download.microsoft.com/download/f/a/c/fac1342d-044d-4d88-ae97-d278ef697064/NETCFv35PowerToys.msi

click i.e. the year 2008 which shows July 26th, you can download it by clicking on that date